# Joining multiple table using loop concept using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to execute following piece of code but end up getting error again and again.

My code is as given below. I am trying to pass key value pair while joining tables but fail to pass value.

```scala
val mainDF = Seq(("1","acv","34","a"),("2","fbg","56","b"),("3","rty","78","c"))
  .toDF("id","name","age","DBName")
val deltaDF = Seq(("1","gbj","67","a"),("2","gbj","67","a"),("2","jku","88","b"),("4","jku","88","b"),("5","uuu","12","c"))
  .toDF("id","name","age","DBName")
    
val nameMap = Map("TT" -> "id")
for ((k,i) <- nameMap) {
  val updatedDF1 = mainDF.as("main")
    .join(deltaDF.as("delta"), $"main.$i" === $"delta.$i" &&  $"main.DBName" === $"delta.DBName", "outer")
    .select(mainDF.columns.map(c => coalesce($"delta.$c", $"main.$c") as c): _*)
  println(s"key: $k, value: $i")
}
    
updatedDF1.show()
```

And the error:

```
Error : <console>:30: error: not found: value updatedDF1
        updatedDF1.show()
```

If anyone can help me or suggest different way to do the same.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Your `updatedDF1.show() ` is out of scope.

Comment: Error:- Error : <console>:31: error: not found: value updatedDF1
       updatedDF1.show()

Comment: `updateDF` is defined inside the loop body, and is not visible outside of it. That is one of several reasons loops are rarely used in scala. There is almost always a better way. I could suggest one in this case, but have trouble understanding what you are trying to do in the first place. What do you want your `updatedDF` to be after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments suggest, the `updatedDF1` declaration becomes out of scope outside of the `for` block and therefore not in the same *lexical scope*. Move the `show` action statement into the for block:

```
val nameMap = Map("TT" -> "id")
for ((k,i) <- nameMap) {
  val updatedDF1 = mainDF.as("main")
    .join(deltaDF.as("delta"), $"main.$i" === $"delta.$i" &&  $"main.DBName" === $"delta.DBName", "outer")
    .select(mainDF.columns.map(c => coalesce($"delta.$c", $"main.$c") as c): _*)
  println(s"key: $k, value: $i")
  updatedDF1.show() 
}
```

To understand why:

- "A block is delimited by braces `{ ... }`."
- "The definitions inside a block are only visible from within the block."

Points taken from https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/lexical_scopes